# integrate visual studio 2008 with windows driver kit 8.1

Tags: visual-studio, integration, windows-server, wdk, servicepacks

i am using windows 8.1 and my system has both vs 2008 and vs 2013(only mobile application). i am trying to run a code which contains hidsdi.h header in vs 2008.
i want to integrate wdk 8.1 with vs 2008. firstly can i do it? if not than which wdk must i use. i have downloaded the code from
http://wiiyourself.gl.tter.org/ version 1.5 
and wdk8.1 from https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/windows/hardware/gg454513

any kind of help will be appreciated.
thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Like you I also use Visual Studio 2008 together with a newer edition (in my case Visual Studio 2015). I use it exclusively for C/C++ and I use the complete toolset from VS2015 in VS2008, thus using just the VS2008 IDE.

The only thing you need to do is edit the paths in the following files:

```
%VSINSTALLPATH%\VC\vcpackages\VCProjectEngine.dll.config
%VSINSTALLPATH%\VC\vcpackages\AMD64.VCPlatform.config
```

Be sure to delete

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\9.0\VCComponents.dat
```

You can have several config-files and just alternate between them with for example some `mklink` script ie for VS2015 and DDK 7.1.